# Truncating table but leave statistics in place on Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a series of cache-like tables used in an application that I am evaluating for a lift-and-shift to Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

The application uses a series of cache-like tables that are loaded and then used in joins to fact tables (of two or three dimensions, e.g., time, location, product).   The cache-like tables are shared through the application and different reports load rows with arbitrary strings as an identifier in one column and the foreign key for the dimension column in the fact table.

It appears statistics are lost when a table is TRUNCATEd.  Is it possible to keep the statistics as they were via hint, et al?

Comment: what is the use case? When you TRUCATE a table, all that's left is the schema. There is no data hence no statistics. When the table gets rehydrated, there will be new stats based on what gets loaded. Can you elaborate on your use case where you think keeping old stats is valuable?

Comment: The cache-like tables are incrementally loaded throughout the day as the user selections in the UI are translated into operations on the database. So if I collected stats before the users' day they would not be representative as the table would be TRUNCATEd overnight.  Collecting stats in every report  would likely be overkill (and likely introduce locking contention).   I thought I read where one can fake the statistics which I will have to look into if I were to use TRUNCATE.  I can  probably just use DELETE and accept the logging to keep the stats static.

Comment: There's no ability to fake stats. The QO uses stats (and other things) to come up with the best plan it can in a reasonable time. Providing fake stats kinda defeats the purpose of having a cost based QO. The odds of accidentally getting a decent plan using fake stats is the same as getting a decent plan with no stats. Also, stats creation and updating does not introduce locking contention, ever. It may result in blocking but that's not the same as lock contention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not keep the statistics after a 'TRUNCATE'.  Resampling your key columns (not using 'FULL SCAN') does not take that long anyway, in my experience.   This is after all an MPP system.

Re locking, you should know the default transaction isolation level for Azure SQL Data Warehouse is Read Uncommitted so lock contention is not an issue.

The technique for spoofing statistics is not available in Azure SQL Data Warehouse at this time.